# Correctly deserialize an object with deserializer with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need a custom deserializer for casting a string in a complex POJO. The deserialization works until the deserializer is used: in particular when the custom deserializer is used, the non-object properties of my object are not serialized.

I have a restful web service that has a pojo as a parameter.

```
public PreventivoResponse calculate(@FormParam(value = "preventivo") PreventivoWs preventivo) throws Exception;
```

So my class PreventivoWs requires a `fromString(String)` method. Here the class definition:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class PreventivoWs implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -554141724349909424L;
    private ClienteMultiSelect cliente;

    private String riferimento;
    private List<EmailWS> email;

    private String dataritiro;
    private String dataconsegna;
    private Long tipoconsegna;

    private IndirizzoWS partenza;

    private IndirizzoWS destinazione;

    List<ColloWs> colli;

    HashMap<Long, String> services;

...
}
```

Inside the jsonObject i have an enumeration defined as

```
{
  "value" : "A",
  "text"  : "Active"
}
```

but this object require a deserializer to be converted:

```
public class TipoPersonaFGJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<TipoPersonaFG> {

@Override
public TipoPersonaFG deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    JsonToken currentToken = null;
    while ((currentToken = jsonParser.nextValue()) != null) {
        switch (currentToken) {
            case VALUE_STRING:
                switch (jsonParser.getCurrentName()) {
                    case "value":
                        String name = jsonParser.getText();
                        return TipoPersonaFG.valueOf(name);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

and it is annotated on the property:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = TipoPersonaFGJsonDeserializer.class)
private TipoPersonaFG tipo;
```

The fromString method simply call the jackson ObjectMapper:

```
public static PreventivoWs fromString(String jsonString) throws IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PreventivoWs oggetto = mapper.readValue(jsonString, PreventivoWs.class);
    return oggetto;
}
```

If the enum is not specified in the jsonString, it works fine: the object is deserialized perfectly;
If i add the enum in the jsonString, all the object-properties are deserialized (email, cliente, partenza, destinazione,...) but the other properties are ignored (dataritiro,dataconsegna,tipoconsegna).

Why? The custom deserializer broke the standard process of deserialization?

UPDATE:
the parsing process is interrupted when the custom deserializer take place: i moved the `cliente` property (which contains the particular enum) at the end of the json object: now the fields dataconsegna, dataritiro and so on are deserialised.

So the deserialization process ends up when the custom deserializer take place (even the cliente object is interrupted)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
As written in [Jackson Wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers) :

> must NOT process any token beyond value being deserialized (no more, or no less)

So the problem was in the deserializer: you must stop when the END_OBJECT (}) is found, otherwhise the jsonParser go on until the end of the stream, consuming all the other tokens.

```
@Override
public TipoPersonaFG deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    JsonToken currentToken = null;
    String name = null;
    while ((currentToken = jsonParser.nextValue()) != null) {
        switch (currentToken) {
            case VALUE_STRING:
                switch (jsonParser.getCurrentName()) {
                    case "value":
                        name = jsonParser.getText();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case END_OBJECT:
                if(name != null)
                    return TipoPersonaFG.valueOf(name);
                else 
                    return null;
        }
    }
    return TipoPersonaFG.valueOf(name);
}
```

I have added the case condition *END_OBJECT* for consuming only the first '}' and close correctly the parsing of the enum object. The return was moved in the END_OBJECT case because otherwise  the '}' token will remain in the stream and it will go to close the parent of the enum.

So you need to parse your object from '{' token to '}' token